# Pass form values to a javascript function as an object

Tags: javascript, html

say I have a form with several types of inputs with different `name` attributes, and I want to pass these input values to a javascript function when the form is submitted.

Normally, when you submit a form the input values are passed to the server as name-value pairs via a GET or POST request. What I'd like to do is have the form pass those name-value pairs, as an object, to a javascript function.

Now, I realize you can just extract the input values by traversing the DOM  and using the input `id` tags, but I'd like to have my code independent of the specifics of the form. My function shouldn't need to go search for the specific input elements, it should just get the name-value pairs.

Can this be done?

Comment: Look at jQuery's `.serialize()` function

Comment: If jQuery is an option have a look at serialize